"Event Log" tool/menu is missing in the latest Android studio - Giraffe
Could not find "Event Log" tool/menu in the latest Android studio - Giraffe.

Is there a way to get this menu in latest Android studio Giraffe?
Where can we find the event logs other than here like "Gradle sync started" or "Gradle sync finished in 1m 3s 224ms"?

Note: This tile is available in previous Android studio - Dolphin
Android Studio Dolphin:

Android Studio Giraffe (latest one) - missing tile:


Its now changed and shifted on top right side of window.

You can find new notifications section on the top right corner of the editor:

